# Doubt in finding limit of fog(x)

Tags: limits

I know that if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=m$, then $\lim_{x→a}f(g(x))=f(m)$, if $f$ is continuos at $m$

My doubt is why does $f$ have to be continuos because we can find $f(m)$ even if it's discontinuous at $m$

Comment: Compare with what happens when $a=0$, $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\ 1&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq f(a)$, because $f$ may not be defined at $x = a$ (if $f$ is not continuous at $a$). Continuity is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ to hold.

For example, consider the function $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$.

- $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$
- $\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

But, $f$ is not defined at $0$.

Comment: Continuity is, by definition, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$

Comment: @CommandMaster Right, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need $lim_{x\rightarrow m}f(x) = f(m)$, which is the same as $f$ being continuous at $m$ by definition.